# Protecting files using htpasswd but every time it's not accepting the password

Tags: .htaccess, url, .htpasswd, protected-folders

I am using hostinger hosting,

I have my root folder `/public_html`  and I have added the `.htpasswd` file in this folder.

I have another folder called `/publish_html/demo` and I have to protect this folder so I have added the `.htaccess` file to this folder.

Below is the code I have in `.htaccess` file

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "My Protected Folder" 
AuthUserFile /public_html/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

And below is the code that I have in `.htpasswd` file. I have generated from this [link](https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator)

```
Test:$apr1$6z74iw3s$6P2i3Q1XGquJ/W.K5FIVu1
```

Now when I check my `demo` URL then I am getting a popup to add the username and password but every time it's not accepting the details.

Any idea what is the issue? I have checked this on Google but most of the answer saying about the AWS config file. I am using shared hosting.

Comment: `/public_html` might be _your_ "root" on the system, but the path you specified is absolute due to the leading slash, so this is referring to the _server's_ root directory - and as such, it is most likely a _wrong_ path. You need to specify either the full absolute path, or one relative to your ServerRoot.

Comment: @CBroe, in Hostinger, Each domain has there own /public_html folder... and this /public_html is my demo domain only

Comment: That doesn't change the fact, that this certainly will not be the root directory of the whole server. https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583494-what-is-the-path-to-your-website-s-root-home-directory-and-how-to-change-it

Comment: "every time it's not accepting the details" - What happens exatcly? What HTTP response are you getting? What webserver/version are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite, I am entering the username and password but nothing is working.. it's showing again the same popup. I am using wordpress with the latest version. and using Shared hostinger  webserver

Comment: You should look into the http server's error log file, that is where that served documents explicitly _why_ those credentials did not get accepted. You hosting provider should offer some means to access that information. If not you should switch the hoster, since that information is vital to operating a web service. Apart from that I agree with what @CBroe pointed out above: you need to understand the difference between the root of your virtual web server and its root folder and the whole server system with a single root folder. And you need to adjust the path pointing to your `.htpasswd` file